# What is Microsoft.Data.Tools.Prototype?

Tags: sql-server-data-tools

I am working on an application that calls Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices.Deploy(). Something inside that function is looking for Microsoft.Data.Tools.Prototype, but it's not able to load the assembly (Microsoft.Data.Tools.Prototype.DLL).

Here is the exception dump:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException occurred
  _HResult=-2147024894
  _message=Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Tools.Prototype, Version=10.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
  HResult=-2147024894
  IsTransient=false
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Tools.Prototype, Version=10.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
  Source=mscorlib
  FileName=Microsoft.Data.Tools.Prototype, Version=10.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
  FusionLog==== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.Data.Tools.Prototype, Version=10.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/fjohnson/Desktop/App/DatabaseBuilder.WPF/bin/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL

Calling assembly : Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql, Version=10.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.

LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\fjohnson\Desktop\App\DatabaseBuilder.WPF\bin\Debug\DatabaseBuilder.vshost.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.Data.Tools.Prototype, Version=10.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/fjohnson/Desktop/App/DatabaseBuilder.WPF/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Data.Tools.Prototype.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/fjohnson/Desktop/App/DatabaseBuilder.WPF/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Data.Tools.Prototype/Microsoft.Data.Tools.Prototype.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/fjohnson/Desktop/App/DatabaseBuilder.WPF/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Data.Tools.Prototype.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/fjohnson/Desktop/App/DatabaseBuilder.WPF/bin/Debug/Microsoft.Data.Tools.Prototype/Microsoft.Data.Tools.Prototype.EXE.

StackTrace:
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
  InnerException:

Comment: For Pete's sake. Google found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx) by searching for `Microsoft.Data.Tools.Prototype` with just three mouse clicks.

Comment: I have already tried installing / re-installing, updating SSDT. What exactly are you suggesting that this link will help me with? I already looked through a lot of the documentation on that page and searched around for specifics, but found nothing. In general, I realize that this probably has to do with SSDT, I should have specified that in the question, but I just tagged it instead.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is "What is Microsoft.Data.Tools.Prototype?", and the link tells you that it's part of SSDT. If that's not what you're asking, you should [edit] your question to make it more specific.